# What's the difference between doing context.watch vs using a Consumer widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier, flutter-change-notifier-provider

What is the difference between using `context.watch<Counter>().count` from the [example on the Provider package page](https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example) and using a Consumer widget when trying to use the provider values?

**Using context.watch().count to get the current value:**

```
class Count extends StatelessWidget {
  const Count({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      /// Calls `context.watch` to make [Count] rebuild when [Counter] changes.
      '${context.watch<Counter>().count}',
      key: const Key('counterState'),
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
    );
  }
}
```

**Using a Consumer widget:**

```
class Count extends StatelessWidget {
  const Count({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Counter>(
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return Text(value.count);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**Counter class:**

```
class Counter with ChangeNotifier, DiagnosticableTreeMixin {
  int _count = 0;

  int get count => _count;

  void increment() {
    _count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Makes `Counter` readable inside the devtools by listing all of its properties
  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(IntProperty('count', count));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Effectively nothing.
`Consumer` is doing nothing outside of calling `context.watch` and sending that to `builder`.

The main reason `Consumer` exists is:

- It can easily be placed over a specific widget in the widget-tree. This enables rebuilding only said widget when the provider changes – without having to create a custom `Stateless/StatefulWidget`.
- If a widget creates a Provider and directly wants to consume it, their `BuildContext` likely wouldn't have access to the Provider. Using `Consumer` solves this problem as it would be under the Provider.
- It can be used inside MultiProvider if you want to have more advanced provider logic.

Comment: I guess `context.*` gives you the option of either watching for changes or just returning the provider without listening. Consumer doesn't really give you the `context.read` option, right?